# How to verify a x509 certificate from Apple on a Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ios, macos, x.509, .net

I'm trying to verify GameCenter authentication on an iOS app with GameKit. The [fetchItems API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayer/3516283-fetchitems) returns a URL for the public key needed to do this.

Steps 3 and 4 of that API say:

> 3. Use the publicKeyURL on the third-party server to download the public key.
> 4. Verify with the appropriate signing authority that Apple signed the public key.

The public key URL I usually get is https://static.gc.apple.com/public-key/gc-prod-5.cer.

On my Mac, I simply download this cert and call [X509Certificate2.Verify() in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?view=net-5.0), and it returns true. However, calling this function on an Ubuntu server returns false. The error message I get on the server from [X509Chain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=net-5.0) is:

> Status information: unable to get local issuer certificate

The cert in question appears to be `CN=Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US`.

How do I get this cert on my Ubuntu server, so that I can verify the public key from Apple? Is there a common registry of certs where I can download it?

Comment: Here's the result of running `openssl x509` on the public key: https://pastebin.com/VGC8M9EF

Comment: The cert I need seems to be http://sv.symcb.com/sv.crt, from the "Authority Information Access" section. Is `X509Certificate.Verify()` supposed to download that automatically?

Comment: Well, it works on CentOS, so this is just a Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your root certificate store as in this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

If I read your question right...looks like you have a copy of the cert?